# Page built using the Transclusion syntax are not properly refreshed

Tags: mediawiki, transclusion

I'm using mediawiki 1.26.3 as knowledge repository with standard configuration and installed the [Visual Editor](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VisualEditor) Extension

Some pages of my wiki are builded dynamically merging the contents of others pages using the [Transclusion](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Transclusion) syntax

> {{:pagename}}

(inclusion of the content of a document into another document by reference)

Follow a piece of the pages inclusions code

> {{:Server_Wrk}}
>
> {{:Client_ Wrk}}
>
> {{:GUI_Wrk}}
>
> {{:Compoments_Wrk}}

In this manner I've the contents from some source pages that are merged in a result page showed to the user

But, if I do some change in one of the source page, the result page contents are not properly updated until I open in edit mode the result page, do a insignificant change (eg. adding a blank space somewhere) and save the result page.

As brower I'm using Firefox and to avoid the browser cache involvement I've do many times

> CTRL + F5

I've edited all the pages using the default editor avoiding possible interaction with the Visual Editor extension

Some one can help me ?

**More**

- I've disabled the Visual Editor extension: the problem still remain
- I've also tested this type of page in a previous installation of our wiki based on the mediawiki version 1.19.8and this behaviour do not happens

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer provided by [Ciencia Al Poder](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User:Ciencia_Al_Poder) in this [page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:T5hru4z2ukikg6io) I've solved.

For this kind of issue refer to the [Job_queue](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Job_queue) page